# Python - Attempting to calculate the average time of events prior to time t

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-average

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ID  Date
1   2/3/18
1   2/7/18
1   2/14/18
1   2/16/18
```

Here is what the final feature will look like:

```
ID  Date     Running_Mean
1   2/3/18   0
1   2/7/18   4
1   2/14/18  5.5
1   2/16/18  4.33
```

This is a rolling window that starts at the beginning of a sequence and continues to expand with the dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `expanding` same thing with `rolling` when `windows = len(df)`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.Date.diff().dt.days.expanding(1).mean()
Out[654]:
0         NaN
1    4.000000
2    5.500000
3    4.333333
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Notice I will recommend keep the first value as NaN since that means not available 0 means different is 0 days that is different

Comment: I'm getting an `IndexError: unsupported iterator index` error when I'm trying it on my dataset. I'm just looking at a column filled with `np.datetime64` values

Comment: @madsthaks I have no idea where this error come from .